# how to destroy an item after collision

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, bullet

I am creating an fps game, I have created the gun, the bullet, and the enemy.
Now I want to make my enemy destroyed after the collision with bullet.
My enemy is a gameobject named Fire and tagged Enemy and my bullet named "Cube 1(Clone)" and tagged "Cube 1(Clone)". I made a script for that:

```
#pragma strict

function OnTriggerEnter(theCollision : Collider)
{
    if(theCollision.gameObject.name=="Cube 1") 
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Debug.Log("Dead");
    }
}
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Java != JavaScript and JavaScript != UnityScript and tag [tag:unity] is a totally different Unity (not the game engine [tag:unity3d])

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the tag not the name. You could check for name but remember it will have "(Clone)".

```
function OnTriggerEnter(theCollision : Collider)
{
    if(theCollision.tag == "Cube 1") 
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Debug.Log("Dead");
    }
}
```

---

If you are not sure that you tagged correctly, you can simply use both checks in your if statement.

```
if(theCollision.tag == "Cube 1" || theCollision.gameObject.name == "Cube 1(Clone)") 
    Destroy(gameObject);
```

Comment: and now I have this error "Assets/Collision1.js(1,4): BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'theCollision'."

Comment: @LakehalAmine Make sure that your code is inside the `OnTriggerEnter()` function. Make sure it looks just like my code above.

Answer (score -1):

Well since the bullet is tagged `Cube 1(Clone)` , I would use

```
if(theCollision.tag == "Cube 1(Clone)"){...}
```

And would probably would rename the tag to something meaningful, say `bullet`.