# OnTriggerEnter2D getting called

Tags: c#, collision, unity3d-2dtools

I'm trying to destroy the enemy if it's colliding with a bullet. But the OnTriggerEnter2D is not working. I've been trying to solve this and searching for answers for hours but I can't seem to find the problem.

**Enemy Script**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform target;
    [SerializeField]
    private float speed;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("Colliding with trigger");
        if (collision.CompareTag("bullet"))
        {
            Debug.Log("I got hit");
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Bullet

[image: bullet prefab inspector]
[image: bullet prefab inspector]

Enemy

[image: enemy inspector]
[image: enemy inspector]

Comment: When you tried `OnCollisionEnter2D`, did you also change the parameter to `Collision2D`?

Answer (score 2):

If it's an actual object that collides with another you want to use `OnCollisionEnter2D` instead. Triggers are for objects that can't be collided with and you just want to know if they're overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

Try switch the isTrigger on the collider instead of the bullet.

Please refer also to this documentation on how to create 2d collider : [how to destroy an item after collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943975/how-to-destroy-an-item-after-collision)

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is my first help post and 2 and a half years late... but I had a similar issue and maybe could help someone else. If you have an "Enemy" script try this. I use the word smash to avoid built in words like destroy or break.

Use this to call: within the < > place the objects "Tag" between the < > to destroy the object. *Enemy in this case*

collision.GetComponent< Enemy >().Smash();

---

In the "Enemy" script use an IEnumerator "Coroutine"

```
IEnumerator SmashCo()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.3f);
    this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Call this Coroutine within the "Enemy" script:
Note: *animator is a reference to Unity's Animator*

```
public void SmashEnemy()
{
    animator.SetBool("smash", true);    // Set the animator Bool for smash
    StartCoroutine(SmashCo());
}
```

---

Add a trigger called smash to your game object.
You should be able to destroy anything like this.

- Taylor

Note: Used Stack Overflow in the shadows for a long time, this is my first post and I would like to be corrected if I am wrong about anything thank you. Just trying to help. *Thought this was a different approach to the current answers.